# Trouble encoding avro enum with null default

Tags: java, avro

```
org.apache.avro.UnresolvedUnionException: Not in union ["null",{"type":"enum","name":"document_change_type","namespace":"document","symbols":["create","update","delete"]}]: create
```

I am passing in the string `create` for this field, and it is throwing the above exception.

`create` is one of the 3 acceptable values for the enum, what is causing the exception?

Answer (score 7):

Suppose your avro schema looks this:

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "namespace" : "document",
  "name" : "document_details",
  "fields" : [
              { "name" : "documentName" , "type" : "string" },
              {"name" : "documentChange" , 
                        "type" : ["null", 
                                  {"type" : "enum",
                                  "namespace" : "document",
                                   "name" : "documentChangeType",                                
                                   "symbols" :["create","update","delete"]
                                   }]
               }            
             ]
}
```

You can create the Record for this schema in your code as :

```
  GenericRecord documentDetailsRecord = new GenericData.Record(schema);
  GenericEnumSymbol enumSymbol = new GenericData.EnumSymbol(schema.getField("documentChange").schema().getTypes().get(1), "create");
  e2.put("documentName", "someDocumentName");
  e2.put("documentChange",enumSymbol);
```

You can get a list of schema for all the fields of union as follows :

```
schema.getField(<unionFieldName>).schema().getTypes()
```